# How can I create a 301 redirect with non-English characters in the URL?

Tags: redirects, 301-redirect

I would like to do 301 redirect from `http://www.test.de/kollektion/b%C3%BCgel%20bh` to `http://www.test.de/bhs/bugel-bhs+balconette`.

I tried to create a redirection rule, but it's not working even though I converted `%C3%BCgel%20bh` into ASCII code.

Comment: Can you add what you've tried to your question?

Comment: @dan as the first sentence but it's not redirected.

Answer (score 1):

To get this to work you will need to use the correct characters rather then the URL encoded characters.

Try adding the following in apache configuration file (apache2.conf/httpd.conf/apache.conf dependent on your distro)

```
AddDefaultCharset UTF-8
```

After restart apache using:

```
sudo service httpd restart
```

or

```
sudo service apache2 restart
```

Then in your htaccess file try the following:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
Redirect 301 http://www.test.de/kollektion/bügel[\s]bh http://www.test.de/bhs/bugel-bhs+balconette
```

Comment: Nice one. Was hoping the OP would provide his _.htaccess_ code so we could see the redirect link, but you decoded it for him.

Comment: @LiamSorsby bügel[\s]bh in the redirection rule that you provide turn into alien language when i put it into httpd.conf of my site.

Comment: @DexterMoregan the bottom should be in your htaccess file not your httpd.conf file. Only the AddDefaultCharset UTF-8 should be added into your httpd.conf